# Limit call to recent media

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Is there a limit call to recent media? The below call should be under Get method base on [instagram limit](https://instagram.com/developer/limits/)?

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an api call to get recent media by tag, the rate limit is 5,000 / hour per application for unauthenticated calls. For authenticated calls, the rate limit is 5,000 / hour per token.

The other rate limits you were seeing on their page at https://instagram.com/developer/limits/ only have to do with posting likes, comments and relationships. Those are much lower numbers per hour.